# Karate - how to choose option in selection component according to option value

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I would like to ask you for a help with option selection according to specific value (value is stored in variable defined in karate-config.js).

I have this case:

```
<select name="environmentId" id="environmentId" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled="">--- Select Environment ---</option>
  <option value="omi-test-env">omi-test-env</option>
  <option value="env-rab">env RAB</option>
</select>
```

I am able to select it via index, but I need to select option with value="env-rab". I have tried something like that, but It did not work:

```
* script("document.getElementById('environmentId').options.value="+ envName)
* script("document.getElementById('environmentId').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('change', {bubbles: true}))")
```

or

```
* script("document.getElementById('environmentId').value="+ envName)
* script("document.getElementById('environmentId').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('change', {bubbles: true}))")
```

I have doubts if I use envName variable in this case correctly (variable is defined in karate-config.js).

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, `select()` supports a string as the second argument:

```
* def envName = 'env-rab'
* select('#environmentId', envName)
```

Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#select

EDIT try this:

```
* script("document.getElementById('environmentId').value='" + env-rab + "'")
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay! The select did not work for me in my situation (but in different place works fine, your help appreciated), but I have find out that in my situation works with script:  
  #  * script("document.getElementById('environmentId').value='env-rab"). But I have tried change 'aaa-env-test' for variable (* def envX = 'env-rab'), but I was not successful. I have tried:  script("document.getElementById('environmentId').value=<envX>") or script("document.getElementById('environmentId').value=#envX").... How can I use variable in script string? Thank you!

Comment: @RadimBukovský see my edit. also please try to get the help of someone who knows javascript

Comment: thank you  -that works perfectly! Now I can use first or second way and I am able to use any select in my project now.